# Javascript change h1 text not inner other html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text of `h1` tag but not other inner `html`. Here is my code

```
document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'Candidate Application Forms';
```

HTML code

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>All Forms <a class="title-action" href="">Add New</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change only `<h1>All Forms</h1>` text not other inside the tag.

I need to do it without `jQuery`

Comment: Wrap 'All Forms' inside a <span id="target-this"> ?

Comment: Marking this as duplicate. While my answer is for jQuery it's the same solution in normal js.

Comment: @KФ: Please edit your answer on  the other question to also include the non-jQuery answer. Otherwise, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @KФ Cheers. Sealed the deal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you do not want to change your document's current structure, I suggest you to change only the *first child* of the H1 node:

```
var h1=document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
h1.firstChild.nodeValue='Candidate Application Forms';
```

Comment: Downvoting is right, but a comment on it won't hurt my sensibility either...

Answer (score 2):

Insert an extra span like this:

```
<div id="wpbody-content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1><span id="allForms">All Forms</span> <a class="title-action" href="">Add New</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

then manipulate it with:

```
document.getElementById('allForms').innerHTML = 'Candidate Application Forms';
```

Comment: But i have no way to use `span` within `h1` tag

Comment: @user3384985 If you can't add `<span>`, you can manipulate the Text node. But `<span>` is the recommended solution - you should trust this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put All Forms  in span with id like

```
<span id="spanId">All Forms </span>
```

now change content of span with id

Answer (score 1):

If you want this without changing HTML:

But the best way is probably to wrap `All Forms` into an element, and change it.

```js
var elt = document.getElementById("wpbody-content")
    .getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];

elt.innerHTML = 'Candidate Application Forms ' + elt.children[0].outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
    <div class="wrap">
         <h1>All Forms <a class="title-action" href="">Add New</a></h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the **HTML** in the wrap-html tag, you could use javascript `replace` function on the `innerHTML` String, with an easy regular Expression like `/<h1>[^<]*/`.

> **`/<h1>[^<]*/`**   matches "<h1>...until next less-then-sign (`<`)"

here is an example:

```js
   var newHeader = 'Candidate Application Forms'
   var htmlValue = document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("wpbody-content").getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0].innerHTML = 
htmlValue.replace(/<h1>[^<]*/,"<h1>" + newHeader);
// Tested with Win7 on Chrome 46+
```

```html
<div id="wpbody-content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1>All Forms <a class="title-action" href="">Add New</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thou shalt not replace regex over living DOM document.

Comment: @TomášZato I change my code "optimation" back, was trying to make a ***oneliner***.

Comment: Your edit has no effect on performance. It's simply bad idea alltogether, sorry.

Comment: @TomášZato, why didnt you down vote other `innerHTML`answers since `innerHTML` changes are in general all, not the best for performance. :)

Comment: I'm not paid for downvoting every shitty answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

## [tl;dr jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z7qutp2/)

Every chunk of text is actually a [TextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Text). You can imagine your HTML like this:

```
<h1>
    <text data="All Forms" />
    <a class="title-action" href="">
        <text data="Add New" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

You can access those elements using `HTMLElement.childNodes` property:

```
var children = elm.childNodes;
for(var i=0,l=children.length; i<l; i++) {
    if(children[i] instanceof Text)
        return children[i];
}
```

`HTMLElement.children` is a list without `Text` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add an id to your element and you can change it as you want.

```
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="it is changed";

<div id="wpbody-content">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1 id="change">All Forms <a class="title-action" href="">Add New</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```